# Remove Attachments sharepoint

Tags: development, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise

I am trying to remove an Attachment from SPList , i would like to remove it from an webpart , that uses an Listbox and an Delete Button

```
oreach (SPListItem customer in items)
            {
                // ett fält som är dolt som håller i idet
                HiddenField1.Value = customer["ID"].ToString();
                TextBox_Name.Text = customer["Title"].ToString();
                TextBox_ProdNum.Text = customer["ProductNumber"].ToString();
                TextBox_Color.Text = customer["Color"].ToString();
                TextBox_ListPrice.Text = customer["ListPrice"].ToString();
                TextBox_MoreInfo.Text = customer["More Info"] != null
                                            ? customer["More Info"].ToString()
                                            : string.Empty;



                ListBox1.Items.Add(new ListItem(customer.Attachments.Add(// here it ask for an leaf but i dont know what it is)));
```

Comment: I suggest to you to have the listitemid and the title in your listitem

Comment: how do u mean...

Comment: have you problem to identify in which SPListItem you must delete the attachment?

Comment: I have created an WebPart that searches for an Product in a List that show the product in an ListBox When presseing Make Changes button i have created an Listbox and an Button there i would like to update the Attachment in that are in my list....

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/VnYCm.png like this but i am insted using an listbox and button instead for an fileupload

Comment: ok but I don't understand which is your problem :-\

Answer (score 0):

```
            SPFolder library = web.Folders[documentLibraryName];

            // Prepare to upload
            Boolean replaceExistingFiles = true;
            String fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileToUpload);
            FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(fileToUpload);

            // Upload document
            SPFile spfile = myLibrary.Files.Add(fileName, fileStream, replaceExistingFiles);

            // Commit 
            myLibrary.Update();
```

I think it's good enought